# Using HTML5 Semantic Elements with BEM Methodology

Tags: html, css, bem

Is it a good practice to use HTML5 semantic elements with BEM? E.g. is

```
<header class="header header--full">
    <nav class="header__nav">...</nav>
</header>
```

OK or I should use *divs* instead?

Comment: This works just fine. Exactly how I do it.

Comment: What about CSS? How do you access such blocks and elements?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking?

Comment: Class only, element name or both? `.header__nav {}`, `nav {}` or smth. like `nav.header__nav {}`?

Comment: Oh always class only. You never want to qualify your selector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the semantic elements. Your example is exactly how you should do it.